# Figure out where ConfigMap values are used in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

In my team we have a single huge ConfigMap Resource that holds all the important variables distributed to all our pods.

After some time we realized that it is very hard to follow up where those variables are finally used. I was wondering if there is any way with Helm or `kubectl` to figure out where the values of the ConfigMap are actually used. Like a list of all the pods being supplied by the ConfigMap etc.

I researched for it but somehow it seems nobody is talking about that. Therefore I might understand the concept wrong here?

Am thankful for any guidance here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly use kubectl [field selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields) to get the result. You can output all the pods in json and use `jq` to query from the output. For example, this query outputs name of all pods that uses configMap "kube-proxy" as volumes

```sh
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.spec.volumes[].configMap.name=="kube-proxy")' | jq .metadata.name
```

Comment: I have not managed to get this to work. That's why I wait for this being the correct answer. Please have some patience :)

Comment: @xetra11, Can you please specify what kind of error you are getting ? Or you are not getting the exact thing what you wanted. If you specify briefly, I think I can help with that.